# What metrics could I use to compare multiple 2-dimensional histograms/sinograms?

Tags: histogram, metric, wasserstein

I have a set of two-dimensional shapes, each represented by one or more closed paths, which enclose one continuous area. My objective is to establish a measure of similarity between these shapes. I do not have a rigid definition of similarity; it might encompass characteristics such as slightly jagged edges or a small hole in one of the shapes. The quality of the comparison will be tested empirically.

I am seeking a method for shape comparison that invariant under rotation, translation and mirroring, but not scaling.

My current idea is to use the Radon transformation (creating a sinogram) as a descriptor for each shape, based on the area enclosed by the paths. I can ensure rotation invariance by employing circular cross-correlation to align the sinograms along the angle axis. I plan to calculate the distance to a mirrored version of the sinogram which would make my calculation mirror-invariant.

While I am not time-constrained when initially calculating the sinograms, I need to be able to quickly find potential matches when given a new shape. This is why I want to use a metric. My goal is to use this to sort the shapes by their descriptors (potentially relative to an all-zero histogram?) and find potential matches more quickly. My database could contain up to tens of thousands of shapes.

At the moment, I am employing Earth Mover's Distance to compare the sinograms. However, I am curious if there are any alternative metrics that I could use?

Comment: I would recommend the Earth Movers Distance, but it sounds to me like you don't want it. Can you tell us why?

Comment: That was not my intention, I like the earth mover's distance, but is it defined on 2d histograms? I might have to reformulate the question if that's the impression you're getting from it

Comment: It indeed is, and this makes perfect sense: you move the "earth" over a two-dimensional area rather than across a one-dimensional line. The `emd2d` function in the [`emdist` package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emdist) does this. I unfortunately don't know enough about Python to recommend anything there.

Comment: That does make sense, as you say and I thought so too, until the missing packages made me uncertain. I'll need to find an implementation or make one myself, thank you for the linked package which will serve as inspiration.

Comment: I also reworked the question to be more clear, I hope it helped. If not, please feel free to edit, but I will also come back to it to make it more future proof.

Comment: To me, "discrete ... histogram" is an inherent contradiction because histograms are graphical methods to represent probabilities (or frequencies) by means of *areas* and nonzero areas cannot reasonably be considered discrete.  Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I meant that the underlying data is not continuous but has a finite number of distinct values. So maybe I should not call the histogram discrete but the data? Now that I think about it, it probably doesn't matter what kind of underlying data is used, I propose I could just edit out the "discrete" part?

Comment: Right.  So you have a histogram, which effectively reduces the information in your data, and you state that "they are not normalized to preserve information," which -- whatever that really means -- doesn't sound like it lends itself to further quantitative analysis.  Moreover, in order to choose an appropriate basis to compare things, you need to know *why* you're doing that comparison.  Thus, there's just not enough information (yet) in your post to make it answerable.

Comment: I made a substantial edit to the question body in order to describe the context of my question . Thank you for the constructive criticism, I hope this helps.

Comment: A simple, effective technique to assure invariance under any specified group $G$ of transformations is to using *intrinsic* properties of the shapes to identify a unique representative of their orbits.  For instance, by translating a shape to place its barycenter at the origin you obtain translation invariance.  By then identifying a unique direction from that barycenter--perhaps the direction towards a point furthest from the barycenter--and rotating that direction to 0 degrees you obtain rotation invariance, *etc.* *How you do this depends on the possible shapes.*

Comment: (Continued) Because it appears your shapes are bounded topological disks, the first few bivariate moments -- barycenter, inertial tensor, and so on -- are likely to determine a unique representative under translations and rotations; the third moment will like determine a unique representative under the full Euclidean group. Then, you only need to compare two of these *standardized* shapes, of which there are a huge variety of solutions depending on your application.